# How to open/handle multiple links using javascript on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I use JavaScript to open multiple links on a single click:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function open_win() { window.open("http://bbbbbbbbbbbb.com/") window.open("http://ccccccccccccccc.com/") } </script>

<button onclick="open_win()">Click me</button>
```

It's working but on the android browser when I click to call this JavaScript, chrome opens 3 tabs.
Now when i switch to http://ccccccccccccccccc.com 
and then the press back button the browser goes back to the first tab *( tab have button Click me)*

but not the tab with the url http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbb.com.

When i press the android back button i want to switch to http:/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.com.

Please help me! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

load single file "http://bbbbbbbbbbbb.com/" in your main file

then load "http://ccccccccccccccc.com/" from "http://bbbbbbbbbbbb.com/", in its onload event

hope this will help

Comment: That is link, not my file @@!